# Как ответить на сообщение присланное в беседе? Vk api

Tags: php, python, vkontakte-api

Имею бота который должен запоминать ID сообщения и по команде ответить на него
(Хоть даже через неделю, но должен). Ну ответить я думаю вы поняли что это. Но когда я это делаю мне пишет что невозможно отметить на это сообщение (использую Токио группы)

Comment: Что значит невозможно ответить? Обычно ВК возвращает конкретные ошибки. Было бы хорошо привести ее здесь в качестве примера, а также код, которым вы "отвечаете" на сообщение

Comment: Сейчас не могу прислать код, но он пишет что не возможно ответить на это сообщение, хотя если использовать vk api на vk.com, то работает, те же самые параметры, я думаю это из за того что токен группы